# My webpage og metas don't not get read

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I added some meta og so when people share the page...well you know.

Thing is when you try to share page like: http://mypage.com , it is as if the page did not have anything in it, whereas when I do http://mypage.com/index.html it reads all meta properly.

Any thoughts? I tried everything!

Cheers,

Otto

Comment: What do you mean by "meta og"?

Comment: try running both url types in the linter - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

this will both show you:
any errors 
and will force facebook to update it's cache for both pages.

Comment: if still error sharing the links would be useful.

Comment: @pek - [Open Graph `og:meta` tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)... It's Facebook developers jargon... nothing you want to get into... believe me ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a caching issue on Facebook's end.  http://mypage.com and http://mypage.com/index.html are treated as different pages, one may be cached by Facebook and the other wasn't yet or something.  Even using the linter tool (developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) may not refresh the cache at Facebook and start using your new OG tags.  We had this issue with meltedjoystick.com and we simply had to wait for the cache to be corrected when the pages were re-crawled.  Took about 10 days for us.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be a lot easier to answer your question if you actually linked your page, the opengraph tags are really quirky so anything could be the issue.

The most common issue is with the og:url tag. Are you supplying one? Is it pointed at the correct place? While you may think that Facebook looks at your page to get the og:description and the rest of the information, it actually looks at your page for the og:url then goes to the URL specified in that tag to find the actual data.

Other than that, be sure to use the [OpenGraph debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to see if you can spot any easy issues. Look for redirects in the top section and click the link on the bottom section to view the page exactly as Facebook sees it.